# MySQL View 1:Many table show all related records in a single row

Tags: mysql, view, row

I need to have a MySQL View that returns a single row for each invoice number and all related records

Invoices

```
--------------------------------------------
|InvoiceID| CustomerID | InvoiceDetailsID  |
--------------------------------------------
| 1       | 1001       | 2200              |
--------------------------------------------
| 2       | 2000       | 2100              |
--------------------------------------------
```

Details

```
-----------------------------------------------
| ID      | DetailsID  | Description | Amount |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1       |   2200     | 10211       |  22.00 |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2       |   2200     | 10212       |  12.00 |
-----------------------------------------------
| 3       |   2200     | 10922       |  99.00 |
-----------------------------------------------
| 4       |   2100     | 99111       |   1.00 |
-----------------------------------------------
| 5       |   2100     | 88229       |   4.50 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Need to return the following (details table may have more than 3 records for each DetailsID but I only need to show the
first three for each DetailsID based on the ID)

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| InvoiceID | CustomerID | InvoiceDetailsID | Description_1 | Amount_1 | Description_2 | Amount_2 | Description_3 | Amount_3 | 
-    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | 1001       | 2200             | 10211         | 22.00    | 10212         | 12.00    | 10922         | 99.00    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2         | 2000       | 2100             | 99111         |  1.00    | 88229         |  4.50    | NULL          | NULL     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You'll probably find it's easier to change your application logic so a simple join works (if this is possible). Then you can use a nested select to return three rows per invoice.

Comment: What happens if you have 100 invoice records? are you going to have 200 extra columns? your design is not scalable and frankly is terrible. use application logic to deal with multiple invoice records

Comment: The reason for the single row for each record is for the Tableau Server which requires a flat structure. The application that controls the data CRUD has not problem with the structure. It was designed for scalability but Tableau is the limiting factor.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of ugly, isn't it?

```
SELECT
    d.InvoiceID
  , d.CustomerID 
  , d.InvoiceDetailsID
  , ( SELECT i.Description  FROM InvoiceDetails i
      WHERE i.DetailsID = d.InvoiceDetailsID 
      ORDER BY i.id   LIMIT 0,1
    ) AS Description_1 
  , ( SELECT i.Amount       FROM InvoiceDetails i
      WHERE i.DetailsID = d.InvoiceDetailsID 
      ORDER BY i.id   LIMIT 0,1
    ) AS Amount_1
  , ( SELECT i.Description  FROM InvoiceDetails i
      WHERE i.DetailsID = d.InvoiceDetailsID 
      ORDER BY i.id   LIMIT 1,1
    ) AS Description_2 
  , ( SELECT i.Amount       FROM InvoiceDetails i
      WHERE i.DetailsID = d.InvoiceDetailsID 
      ORDER BY i.id   LIMIT 1,1
    ) AS Amount_2
  , ( SELECT i.Description  FROM InvoiceDetails i
      WHERE i.DetailsID = d.InvoiceDetailsID 
      ORDER BY i.id   LIMIT 2,1
    ) AS Description_3 
  , ( SELECT i.Amount       FROM InvoiceDetails i
      WHERE i.DetailsID = d.InvoiceDetailsID 
      ORDER BY i.id   LIMIT 2,1
    ) AS Amount_3
FROM Details AS d
ORDER BY d.InvoiceDetailsID
```